# In one CodeIgniter controller session is empty, in other all works

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I developed this functionality locally on my laptop and all worked well, but when I uploaded changes on the server, I received an issue.

The check_admin_auth() function checks session variable and it is `NULL` when it calls from my controller (all other controllers in the project with the same code works well).

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ctransaction extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->auth->check_admin_auth(); // this function
         /* checks one session item to check is user logged and admin or not,
            if not - redirects to login page. But in my case redirecting doesn't apply,
            I see just white screen, page status 200. */
        $this->db->query('SET SESSION sql_mode = ""');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // some code here
        $content = $this->parser->parse('gltransaction/list', $data, true);
        $this->template->full_admin_html_view($content);
    }

    public function ajaxLoadGLTransactions()
    {
        // some code here
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

Please, can you help me to find where the problem is?
I think that's settings in `php.ini` or in the same place, but I didn't find a reason.

I tried to modify `/system/libraries/Session/Session.php` as it was recommended in web, but it didn't help.

Files with sessions are created in folder `/application/ci_sessions` and they stored all necessary data, but for some reason, my controller doesn't load it and returns on its page session with only one field - `__ci_last_regenerate`.

The library session is loaded in autoloader in configuration file.

Cookies are the same on working pages and on page of my controller.

CI Version 3.1.4

PHP Version 7.2.32

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that before `<?php` I've added one more line. The file of controller was like:

```
// empty line without anything
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
// and all other code
```

Didn't think that it can make sense!